# How to open the specified page on ios by receiving a push notification

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I have registered the device token

```
this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
  return this.push.saveToken(t);
}).then((t: PushToken) => {
  console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
});
```

And also I am receiving push notification. This is woking fine. 
But I want to open a specific view page on push click.

Push handle here:

```
this.push.rx.notification()
  .subscribe((msg) => {
    alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
  });
```

Any idea?

Comment: are you getting something as notification type from your backend, so that navigation may work smooth

Comment: is there any need to enable background notification?

Comment: yes , u need to check that , whether your application is in background or foreground. Like :
   if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
} , it is actually needed to know that what are the responses from your backend.

Comment: ok fine, how can get the playload items?

Comment: why not use the Navcontroller to push the view?

Comment: ya... Navcontroller also working fine

Comment: Guys tell me how to get the playload items from backend push

Comment: are u using chrome inspector?

Comment: No.i am testing on device

Comment: use ionic run android --l --c , and then u may use chrome://inspect , over there you may choose your device and then u can use debugging options to catch your backend response